# nodejs: forever not responding

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, forever

So I know, it was not the most smartass idea, but I updated nodejs to version 0.10 with "n" while the server was still running with forever.
Now when I try typing in

```
$ forever list
```

or

```
$ forever stopall
```

or

```
$ forever restartall
```

it simply does nothing. Anyways -

```
$ forever --help
```

still shows the help menu, but all actions won't work. And my nodejs Server is still responding!

Is there any method I can kill forever with fire?

Comment: What about just killing the process, if that fails, which it won't. What about restarting?

Comment: oh man, why haven't I thought of this. Thx! I'm not really used to work with linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok with a litte help i solved the problem:

Just type in

```
$ ps aux | less
```

and search for all processes that have to do something with nodejs and kill them with

```
$ kill -9 *PID HERE*
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
sudo killall node
```

OR

```
sudo forever stopall
```

If that too doesn't work simply use

```
sudo kill -9 $(ps aux | grep 'node' | awk '{print $2}')
```

Hope this works

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this problem in monitoring daemons in general, such as forever and hotnode. As you indicated, you can grep the pids of the lost processes. I went so far as to add `killall node` to my production boot script, actually (a little less wordy than your solution, and a bit overkill, but it's effectively solved the problem).